# std::map operator< pointer address compare vs pointer value compare

Tags: c++11, pointers

I was investigating how map handles custom types and I came across some odd behavior.

I created a custom type ´ComplexType´ that has 1 member, a pointer to an int.
I first compared using the value of this int, which gave the expected behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct ComplexType
{
    ComplexType(int i): index(new int(i)){
    };
    ComplexType(const ComplexType& cT): index(new int(*cT.index)){
    }
    ~ComplexType(){
        if(index){
            delete index;
        }
    }
    bool operator<(const ComplexType cT) const
    {
        return *index < *cT.index;
    }
    int* index;

};

int main(){
    int pi[] = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 8};
    std::map< ComplexType , int  > container;
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; ++i){
        container[ComplexType(i)] = pi[i];
    }
    std::cout << "Loop map, size: " << container.size() <<  std::endl;
    for(auto it = container.begin();it != container.end(); it++){
        std::cout << "Show index map, size: " << container.size() <<  std::endl;
        std::cout << *it->first.index << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With the output:

```
Loop map, size: 12
Show index map, size: 12
0
Show index map, size: 12
1
Show index map, size: 12
2
Show index map, size: 12
3
Show index map, size: 12
4
Show index map, size: 12
5
Show index map, size: 12
6
Show index map, size: 12
7
Show index map, size: 12
8
Show index map, size: 12
9
Show index map, size: 12
10
Show index map, size: 12
11
```

Now I changed my compare function to compare on the address of the pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct ComplexType
{
    ComplexType(int i): index(new int(i)){
    };
    ComplexType(const ComplexType& cT): index(new int(*cT.index)){
    }
    ~ComplexType(){
        if(index){
            delete index;
        }
    }
    bool operator<(const ComplexType cT) const
    {
        return index < cT.index;
    }
    int* index;

};

int main(){
    int pi[] = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 8};
    std::map< ComplexType , int  > container;
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; ++i){
        container[ComplexType(i)] = pi[i];
    }
    std::cout << "Loop map, size: " << container.size() <<  std::endl;
    for(auto it = container.begin();it != container.end(); it++){
        std::cout << "Show index map, size: " << container.size() <<  std::endl;
        std::cout << *it->first.index << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expected this to result in a random order based on what addresses the pointer got on the heap. Instead I got the following:

```
Loop map, size: 12
Show index map, size: 12
1
Show index map, size: 12
0
```

I compiled using g++ (GCC) 5.3.0

```
\randomness map>g++ -std=c++11 -o mapConstructionComplexType mapConstructionComplexType.cpp

\randomness map>g++ -std=c++11 -o mapConstructionComplexTypePointerCmp mapConstructionComplexTypePointerCmp.cpp
```

Can anyone explain this odd behavior?

Comment: Missing ampersand, should be `bool operator<(const ComplexType& cT) const`

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior. `operator<` takes `ComplexType` by value, making a copy of the argument. So, when a map wants to calculate `key1 < key2`, you compare `key1.index` with `someTemporary.index`, where `someTemporary.index` is a pointer just allocated on the heap, that bears no relation to `key2.index`. Even calling `key1 < key2` twice could produce different results, let alone satisfying all the requirements of a strict weak ordering.

Comment: Besides, comparing two pointers that don't both point into the same array or to non-static data members of the same object is in itself undefined behavior. This can be salvaged with `return std::less<int*>()(index, cT.index);`

Comment: That indeed solved it and I get why it is undefined behavior refering to the copying and comparing to a new pointer but why does this result in only 2 elements being iterated from a map of size 12?

Comment: @turoni when I use `return rand()%2;` in `operator<`, then I get 5 elements, should I investigate why it happens?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki the class has no practical application for me so investigate only if you are curious as well. I think either the end() iterator gets misplaced or the it++ follows the wrong order. I'm not sure if this is something that can, or should, be investigated because I think it is mostly compiler dependent.

Comment: @turoni You lied to the implementation of `std::map` by providing a false predicate, so it lies to you about the number of elements and its ordering. That's a plain UB

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined: anything whatsoever can happen. See also: [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)